# Cannot Enable Feature Flags in Apache Superset

Tags: configuration, apache-superset

I am using apache-superset 2.0.0 and python 3.9. I have created the superset_config.py file as shown below, exported the SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH and after initializing superset I get the following message "Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/home/...]". However, the enabled features are still not shown when creating/editing charts. Can anybody help me out?

```
# Superset specific config
ROW_LIMIT = 5000
# ---------------------------------------------------
# Feature flags
# ---------------------------------------------------
# Feature flags that are set by default go here. Their values can be
# overwritten by those specified under FEATURE_FLAGS in superset_config.py
# For example, DEFAULT_FEATURE_FLAGS = { 'FOO': True, 'BAR': False } here
# and FEATURE_FLAGS = { 'BAR': True, 'BAZ': True } in superset_config.py
# will result in combined feature flags of { 'FOO': True, 'BAR': True, 'BAZ': True }
FEATURE_FLAGS = {
    "DRILL_TO_DETAIL": True,
        "DASHBOARD_CROSS_FILTERS": True,
        "ALERTS_ATTACH_REPORTS": True,
        "DASHBOARD_NATIVE_FILTERS_SET": True,
        "ALERT_REPORTS": True,
        "DASHBOARD_FILTERS_EXPERIMENTAL": True,
        "ALLOW_ADHOC_SUBQUERY": True,
        "DRUID_JOINS": True
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If using docker-compose, this might be being overwritten by `/docker/pythonpath_dev/superset_config_docker.py` - just one possibility.  If that's the case try adding this code there.

Answer (score 0):

By default, there is already a superset_config.py file that Superset uses. Edit the superset_config.py file in /docker/pythonpath_dev.